# Change default name when a user creates a excel template from document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-template

This document library have a excel template, so every time a user clicks on new and selects the template book.xlsx gets created. Is there any possibility to change this default name to something else then "Book" once it gets created?

If not is there any work around?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing did anyone come up with a solution that doesn't leave the file name in the web app as book.xlsx? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to change the initial name, the user would have to change the name to something useful/unique when saving.

However, I do have a rough fix of a workflow which when a new document is created and saved and the user has closed the document (so they don't still have it checked out) it renames the document. This is just done with the set field value for 'name' on current item.

Not the cleanest but works reliably. Would this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes that would be very greatful!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the file name of an excel file is what the file name defaults to when you create a new document from the template.

Here is a screen shot of a library where I turned on content types and then uploaded an excel file named **Excel File Name**. As you can see when I went to the library and used the new button to open the template that the file name defaults to what the template file name was.

1. Upload your excel template with the file name being what you want to default.
2. After the template is saved the file name appears here.
3. Example of selecting Save As from the template applied to this library.
4. The default file name in the save as box comes from the file name.

[image]

By the way I found that Word documents take the first line of text in the document for the default file name of a new file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the user are using the web version of excel in SharePoint and when you use "Save As" the default becomes book.xlsx no matter what.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using SharePoint 2013 on prem with Office 2016.